# What is the correct way, to configure inflections while in initalization phase of rails? (If there is one)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Edit based on comment:**

To show the problem an easy example:

I put (just for test) this code into application.rb

```
def dev_check_inflections
    puts " - inflection / classify test - " * 4
    %W(WebTrans InplaceTrans Egg Eggs People Data UserData).each {|w|
        puts (" #{w} -> plural:#{w.pluralize} singular:#{w.singularize} classify:#{w.classify}")
    }
end


module Myapp
    class Application < Rails::Application
        dev_check_inflections
    …
end
```

and in environment.rb I put `dev_check_inflections` at the end

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Myapp::Application.initialize!
dev_check_inflections
```

**The test runs on the base of my custom inflection from `initializers/inflection.rb`**

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /^(.*?)data/i, '\1data'
  inflect.singular /^(.*?)data/i, '\1data'
  inflect.plural /^(.*?)Trans$/, '\1Trans'
  inflect.singular /^(.*?)Trans$/, '\1Trans'
  inflect.plural /^(.*?)record/i, '\1records'
  inflect.singular /^(.*?)records/i, '\1record'
  inflect.uncountable %w( login_data data datum)
  
end
```

**The output is this before inflections run:**

WebTrans -> plural:WebTrans singular:**WebTran** classify:**WebTran**

InplaceTrans -> plural:InplaceTrans singular:**InplaceTran** classify:**InplaceTran**

Egg -> plural:Eggs singular:Egg classify:Egg

Eggs -> plural:Eggs singular:Egg classify:Egg

People -> plural:People singular:Person classify:Person

Data -> plural:Data singular:Datum classify:Datum

UserData -> plural:UserData singular:**UserDatum** classify:**UserDatum**

**and this after initialization:**

WebTrans -> plural:WebTrans singular:**WebTrans** classify:**WebTrans**

InplaceTrans -> plural:InplaceTrans singular:**InplaceTrans** classify:**InplaceTrans**

Egg -> plural:Eggs singular:Egg classify:Egg

Eggs -> plural:Eggs singular:Egg classify:Egg

People -> plural:People singular:Person classify:Person

Data -> plural:Data singular:Data classify:Data

UserData -> plural:Userdata singular:Userdata classify:**Userdata**

So any code that relies on custom inflections and has to run before initialization is done, has this problem.

---

I have module named `Configurable`, that helps to make any other module configurable via extend.

Just as example:

```
module Printer
    extend Configurable
    configurable do
        global_attr printer_port: "LPT1"
        …
    end
    …
end
```

In `intializers/printer.rb` and/or `development.rb` I now can put

```
Configurable.setup("Printer") do |config| #as String(!) not to trigger autoload or zeitwerk
    config.printer_port: "LPT5"
end
```

And later use

```
print_something_to(Printer.config.printer_port)
```

In between I instantiate `Configurable::PrinterConfig`

But with `WebTrans` as module I get `Configurable::WebTranConfig` (notice the missing 's')

Well, this is something for `Inflections`, but already when I opened initializers, I smelled the Problem:

I now have to class names `Configurable::WebTranConfig` and
`Configurable::WebTransConfig`, because Inflections are loaded late with init.

This is a funny error, because, if I put it in initializers (only) WebTrans does not have the problem anymore, but BookTrans would have (at least with zeitwerk). B<I<W

So I see 3 solutions:

- Don't rely on the name, generate it ones and live with "WebTran"  (mine)
- Dont't use Classify here (my 2. one)
- Put this inflections in … where?

I tried to put this part into application.rb, that works, but looks really nasty.

Any better Ideas?

Am I the only one stepping into this pitfall?

Comment: It is very unclear what inflection has to do with this based on the wording of the question. It is additionally unclear how these modules are created in the `Configurable` namespace can you please clarify the implementation with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Rails has a boot process. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSza2FZucV8) explains how it works and gives an idea of what happens when.

Once Active Support has been loaded, inflections can be put anywhere, really. They are normally defined in an initializer because that is what the application generator generates. And it is generated there because it is normally enough.

Inflections are global and can be configured anywhere. In this case, you could move them out from the initializers into `lib/inflections.rb` (say, for example), and then in `config/application.rb` load them with `require`.

However, you seem to be configuring constant names to be later constantized when autoloading is available. By that time, the inflections are ready and autoloading will work as per what you have in the initializers (only `camelize` matters to the autoloader). So, I wonder if you truly need to do anything.

Summary, if the runtime that needs the inflections in place gets executed for real before the initializers, move them. Otherwise, leave them where they are because that is the conventional spot.